# How does MySQL use ORDER BY when referencing an indexed prefix on VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, indexing, prefix

I'm curious how this is handled. I have a `varchar(255)` column named `title` that has the first 10 characters indexed.

If I create a MySQL query that orders by title, does it take advantage of that index solely, or does it ignore it, or do I have to issue a command to use that index?

For example let's say I have two `title` items named:

```
This is the same thing
This is the same thing only slightly different
```

The first 10 chars are the same, so how does MySQL handle that? Does it use the prefix index up to the first 10 chars and then row by row index afterwards?

Comment: MySQL may or may not use the index. An EXPLAIN of the statement will show whether the index is being used. With an `ORDER BY title`, using the index will not be sufficient, unless MySQL has some magical way of knowing that no title is over 10 characters long... which I don't think it does, and if it does, it may vary by storage engine (MyISAM vs InnoDB). It's possible that MySQL can make use of the index to optimze the sort, but it's not going to be able to avoid a sort entirely, at least, not using that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's [said](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html) that:

> The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the
>   index exactly, as long as all of the unused portions of the index and
>   all the extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause.

But I strongly suggest checking this query with EXPLAIN, to see which path the optimizer will choose.